# android - volley request inside loop

Tags: android, loops, android-volley, request-queueing

Okay, my first post because I've reached the limits of researching.
I try to run 3 requests, each with a different url inside a for loop (I've tried also with while and if) and the code runs perfectly, untiiiiil it gets to the requestqueue. Now the thing is: after the request queue I want to get the response, and only then make the for loop again, but that does not seem to be what the program wants to do, because after I add the requestqueue, the class goes back to the for loop, and continues the whole function until the end, and only in the end I get 3 followed responses, and it is pissing me off, because I want the requests one at each time. I've done many requests before, and thought I knew how to work this out, but I can't =s
Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private String totalresults, word, results, server, userAgent, quantity, urly, nome;
private int counter,limit;
EditText nome_empresa;
public TextView output;
ProgressDialog PD;
ViewPager viewPager=null;
public ArrayList half_cards, all_cards;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    nome_empresa = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nome_empresa);
    output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
    PD = new ProgressDialog(this);
    PD.setMessage("Loading....");
    PD.setCancelable(false);
    //viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    //FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    //viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapterAlfa(fragmentManager));

}



public void vamos(View view) {
    nome = nome_empresa.getText().toString();
    PD.show();
    googlesearch(nome, 200, 0);
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.custom_list_view);

    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, all_cards));
    all_cards = get_cards(totalresults, nome);
    PD.dismiss();

}

public void googlesearch(String worde, int limite, int start) {
    word = worde;
    results = "";
    totalresults = "";
    server = "www.google.com";
    userAgent = "(Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0;en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6";
    quantity = "100";
    counter = start;
    limit = limite;
    do_search();
}

public void do_search() {

    for(int l=counter; l<=limit; l+=100){
        urly = "http://" + server + "/search?num=" + quantity + "&start=" + Integer.toString(counter) + "&hl=en&meta=&q=%40\"" + word + "\"";
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, urly, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    half_cards = get_cards(response, word);
                    all_cards.addAll(half_cards);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.e("Error: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        });
            requestQueue.add(strReq);
    }
}

public ArrayList get_cards(String ola, String ole){
    myparser rawres = new myparser(ola, ole);
    return rawres.cards();
}
```

}

Comment: `Volley` runs asynchronously, meaning it will run on its own thread while the other code continues to run. So it wont wait for the `Volley response` it will just start the for loop again. Try calling `do_search` within your `onResponse` method with `if statements` determining what `url` to use.

Answer (score 1):

Volley request is asynchronous so when response comes back loop is over some time ago. To do request queue it must be recursive - run next request call in response of previous one.